# Apache mod_rewrite to remove slashes is writing redirect using the filepath not a uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Unfortunately I don't have direct access to this server so trial and error via a proxy person is proving difficult.

We have the following Location directive (along with others) within a VirtualHost directive. It might be worth noting that helloworld is a symlink to a folder somewhere else.

```
<Location /something/helloworld>
    Options FollowSymlinks
 
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>
 
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /something/helloworld/
 
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301] # the $1 seems to be a filepath not a uri
 
        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Location>
```

The rule to redirect the trailing slashes seems to be using a filepath not a uri, and as a result we a curl request like this:

```
curl -I http://www2-dev.example.co.uk/something/helloworld/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 15:38:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www2-dev.example.co.uk/fs1/www/www2-dev.example.co.uk/html/students/helloworld
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Ideally I'm expecting the location header sent back to be

```
Location: http://www2-dev.example.co.uk/something/helloworld
```

As always, many thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: There's a weird flake in httpd: "Substitutions are only treated as a file-system path when the rule is configured in server (virtualhost) context and the first component of the path in the substitution is exists in the file-system" [source: docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) which may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/$ /$1 [NE,L,R=302]` and restart Apache.

Comment: @anubhava unfortunately that rule didn't change the behaviour and it still rewrites to the filepath rather than the URI.

Comment: The issue seems to relate to what @UlrichSchwarz mentions. So if I change the <Location> to a <Directory> directive it solves the problem in isolation. Unfortunately it doesn't work when there is a <Location /something> directive as well (which we have), this seems to take precedence even when it comes below the <Directory> directive.

Comment: Apologies @anubhava, I hit enter which submitted that comment so additional information came in a subsequent comment :-/

Comment: ok try: `RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R=302]`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, unfortunately the same result of including the file path within the rewrite.

Comment: Did you try testing from a different browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Yeah and even directly with `curl` from the command line.